# my sql join on already ordered column desc/get the last data

Tags: mysql, join

i have a table and relationship there is **m_article, process_article and m_process_detail.**

every ***m_article has many process_article***, and every ***m_process_detail has many process_article*** too,

so I want to find the last data from process_article of every article that had id_m_process = '8', i considered the last data is the max of id_m_pa of every article

here is tables

1st is **m_article**

| id_m_article | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LL213 |
| 2 | LL222 |

2nd is **process_article**

| id_m_pa | id_m_article | id_mpd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 41 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 3 | 1 | 42 |
| 4 | 2 | 42 |
| 5 | 2 | 43 |
| 6 | 2 | 40 |

3rd is **m_process_detail**

| id_mpd | id_m_process | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 8 | stiching a |
| 41 | 8 | stiching b |
| 42 | 8 | stiching c |
| 43 | 8 | stiching d |

so i wanted to get the last of the id_mpd on process article of every article in the table, for example article 1 it should be id_mpd = 42 and article 2 it should be id_mpd 40

| code | id_mpd |
| --- | --- |
| LL213 | 42 |
| LL222 | 43 |

this is the query i tried

```
select ma.code, pa.id_mpd
from m_article ma 
join process_article pa on ma.id_m_article = pa.id_m_article 
join m_proses_detail mpd on pa.id_mpd = mpd.id_mpd 
where mpd.id_m_process = '8'
```

with that query i get the first

| code | id_mpd |
| --- | --- |
| LL213 | 42 |
| LL222 | 40 |

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. In code questions give a [mre]. Why do you expect that query to work, justified by referencing authoritative documentation? Give the smallest code with that problem. If you pinned down your wrong expectation & clearly stated it you could google it. What does "already ordered column" mean? A table has no row order, a query result has partial order per an outermost ORDER BY. That is a faq. PS [ask] [Help]

Comment: i edit it, i hope its clear. i wanted the last id_mpd of every article in the process_article that have id_m_process 8 in the m_process_detail

Comment: You really haven't done what I said. Including, you still don't say why, with justification, that query would do what you think it does, or even what you think it does. Including explaining "ordered" or what it has to do with your query being wrong. Etc.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT m.`code`, p.`id_mpd` FROM `m_article` m
JOIN process_article p ON m.`id_m_article`=p.`id_m_article`
JOIN `m_process_detail` d ON p.`id_mpd`=d.`id_mpd`
WHERE p.`id_mpd` IN (SELECT MAX(id_mpd) FROM process_article WHERE id_m_article=m.`id_m_article`)
GROUP BY m.`id_m_article`;
```

**RESULT**

```
code    id_mpd  
------  --------
LL213         42
LL222         43
```

> The WHERE in MySQL clause, when used together with the IN keyword only affects the rows whose values matches the list of values provided in the IN keyword.

[MySQL WHERE Clause: AND, OR, IN, NOT IN Query Example](https://www.guru99.com/where-clause.html)

Comment: can i max (id_m_pa) because the order of id mpd is not always small to big, it can be random , like on id_m_article 2 there is 41,42,43 it can be 41,42,40 and the 40 should be picked because its the last data

Comment: i tried it and it doesnt work, its still selecting the first data, when i changed to id_m_pa instead it return nothing

Comment: @kuin Checkout my new Query. I Modified my Answer.